# php and echoing out string with html tags. string space truncate string and &nbsp; also not working as a replacement

Tags: php, html, mysql, string

MySql: I have my products table set up as follow:

### pg_id | pg_name

1  |  Pizza's calzone
2  |  Kids menu

---

Php: Echo out the html while looping through the records in the MySQL table.

```
<?php do { ?>
<li>
  <?php echo "<a href=". "products.php?p_group=" .$row_getproductnames[ 'pg_name'] . ">"; ?>

  <?php echo $row_getproductnames[ 'pg_name']; ?>
  </a>
</li>

<?php } while ($row_getproductnames=mysql_fetch_assoc($getproductnames)); ?>
```

My hyperlink: The link to the products.php page should look like this for records with white space in it. This post and reference the product names correctly in the products page.

```
http://127.0.0.1/products.php?p_group=Pizza's calzone
```

But it truncates after the white space to

```
http://127.0.0.1/products.php?p_group=Pizza's
```

I have checked numerous samples like using `&nbsp;` in the place of the white space, Html encryption or decryption etc. Still having problem with getting the string to link correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `%20` in place of spaces in a URL

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($row_getproductnames[ 'pg_name']);`?

Comment: It echo out the format and string length : string(15) "Pizza's calzone"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the `href` with double quotes:

```
echo "<a href=\"products.php?p_group=" .$row_getproductnames[ 'pg_name'] . "\">"
```

If you use single quotes or no quotes then the `'` in `pg_name` is misunderstood by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a valid URL, you can will want to replace the spaces with a `+` or `%20`. Either will do. I also suggest removing the apostrophes:

```
$new_url = str_replace(" ","+", $old_url); //Replace space
$new_url = str_replace("'","", $new_url ); //Remove apostrophe
```

**Edit:**

If you are needing to use the name parameter to retrieve an item from the database, you can do it by 're-replacing' the space and apostrophe characters at the other end like this:

Build the url:

```
$new_url = str_replace(" ","+", $old_url); //Replace space
$new_url = str_replace("'","APOSTROPHE", $new_url ); //Remove apostrophe
```

Then at the page where you will perform the `SELECT` query:

```
$product_name = str_replace("+"," ", $product_name); //Put spaces back
$product_name = str_replace("APOSTROPHE","'", $product_name ); //put apostrophes back
```

There are however much easier ways to send values to other pages such as sending a `POST` request

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had this coding before I posted to the page. It removes the quotes but it does not solve the space issue. The names in the products page is being set up by my client. The hyperlink then reference the product name to the products page via the url where a select retrieves the products according to this name stored in the items table. "Select * from itemtable where pg_name = ''Pizza's calzone".

Comment: I have modified my answer to what I think you are wanting. See my edit

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like were on the same page reguarding this. I was checking a work around for this with the $_Post.

<?php echo "<a href='products.php?p_group=" .str_replace(" ' ","*",str_replace(' ', '_',$row_getproductnames['pg_name'])) . "'>"; ?>

Will give me this URL : products.php?p_group=Pizza*s_calzone. 
Will grab the post on the products.php page into a var and then manipulate the string back to correct format. Thank you for your input. Appreciated.

Comment: No problem at all! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your not using quotes? I don't know for sure this is causing it but usually with any parsing issues quotes will fix it.

Try replacing this line:

```
<?php echo "<a href='products.php?p_group=" .$row_getproductnames[ 'pg_name'] . "'>"; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I had this in quotes before and it comes out as : products.php?p_group=Pizza. The string is broken at the 's.

Comment: Try double quotes, or addslashes to stop that single quote from breaking the patterm